# Terrain LOD Camera Moving Crack

Tags: opengl, terrain, quadtree, level-of-detail

I have a grid based terrain and a quadtree for lod.
In one simulation step i do the following:

1. handle input.
2. update matrices.
3. build quadtree (view frustum culling, distance check).
4. close cracks.
5. copy enabled points to the vertex array.
6. draw vertex array.

Naturally without checking for unconnected points I get cracks between neighboring quads with different lod.

I can close all gaps while my camera stand still.

But the problem is, while my camera is moving, there are visible cracks between some quads that have changed after the last frames.

Comment: How wide are the artifacts? This might be a result of subpixel arithmetic.

Comment: they are very small. only a small line or egde. i will check if the artifact size depends on the quad size/ terrain resolution

Comment: I think it is not dependant on the terrain resolution but the rastering phase of the pipeline. The three triangles are not handled exaclty the same. Try to check it there are artifacts when lowering the rendering resolution.

Comment: mhh i have these problem with every resolution. i will try to collapse the unshared point instead of linking it.

Comment: ok i think i solved it :-). i used std::vector functions with integer indices and so i got overflows with the vertex arrays of cracked quads